# How can I apply a css transition to an element when its parent is hovered?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I have the html:

```
<div class="social-section">
    <a href="#" class="glyphicons facebook"><i></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="glyphicons twitter"><i></i></a>
</div>
```

I'd like to have the icon fade to a different color when moused over, using a CSS3 transition. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to make this work, if it's possible. My current attempt at the css is:

```
.social-section * i:before { /* Apply this to the i:before, when the a is hovered */
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.social-section a i:before {
    color: red;
}

.social-section a:hover i:before {
    color: black;
}
```

In case this is helpful, here's the relevant section of the Glyphicons font css code:

```
.glyphicons {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 0 5px 35px;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
}
.glyphicons i:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    font: 20px/1em 'Glyphicons';
    font-style: normal;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Could you post a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) of what you've *got*, and explain how it isn't working? That way we can work with representative code that lets us try and work out what's going on.

Comment: @DavidThomas I can't give an example with the actual font, but here's an accurate alternative I've just finished: http://jsfiddle.net/6sFCs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that pseudo elements aren't capable of transitions on most versions of most browsers. This issue is so frustrating that Chris Coyier (of css-tricks.com) is [keeping a page open](http://css-tricks.com/transitions-and-animations-on-css-generated-content/) on the current status.

As of time of writing, transitions on pseudo elements are supported by:

- Firefox 4.0+
- Chrome 26+
- IE 10+

You can [confirm this](http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/BkhFI) on your browser.

Answer (score 2):

A pseudo-code, since I'm not sure how it should act based on your quesiton...

put the transition css code you have in the element you want to affect (i.e. not the parent)

```
#child {
   // transitions....
}
```

then do

```
 #parent:hover #child {
   // your changes
}
```

When the parent element is hovered, make changes to the child. The child's existing transition effects will be used for this, which I think is your goal.

Also, if you're going to be transitioning between icons, you'll need to change the position of the sprite-image, which I assume you're using, not changing the `color` style.

Comment: A completely reasonable attempt, which unfortunately did not work.

Comment: aright, if you give more of your code I'll try help out....the color style only changes the color of font, not the icons.

Comment: Ah. I'm actually using the Glyphicons font for this, which allows me to just change the color.

Comment: ohhh i thought it was the glyphicons found in bootstrap... cool!

Comment: So, from your code, the hover is working. It isn't changing the color, but the hover does work as your wrote it! I'm not sure `i:before` is the right thing to change, maybe you want to do just `i`? http://jsfiddle.net/rUnQv/ ... sorry I couldn't be of more help. good luck!

Comment: It's worth remembering that the pseudo elements won't/can't transition (insofar as I've yet found, in Opera, Chrome/Chromium and Firefox).